# Ruby how to send text message to mobile phone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, sms

Can someone please guide me on how to send text messages from a Ruby on Rails application to users when you have their cell phone number?  I read about Amazon AWS SNS and SMS, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for in terms of just sending a simple text to someone given a cell number.  I could be mistaken.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a very broad question you're asking. You're asking us to mentor you in ruby... but this is a but beyond the scope of what we normally allow for Stack Overflow questions. Have you googled for tutorials on this subject? If so, at what point did you get stuck while trying out the examples? If you are having trouble with this subject, I suggest you try out your local ruby-users group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [textMagic](https://www.textmagic.com/) and [Github Link](https://github.com/bobes/textmagic).It is a paid service that allows you to send text/SMS messages to people's cell phone numbers.TextMagic offers a free trial that allows you to develop your application without having to pay for a premium account.

Here is the link for [Step By Step Tutorials](https://richonrails.com/articles/sending-sms-using-text-magic).As mentioned in this link, You've to follow following steps

1. Log into TextMagic
2. Click 'Services'
3. Click 'API'
4. Click 'Generate new API password'
5. Enter your account password
6. Copy down the generated API password

#### Install gem

```
gem 'textmagic', '~> 0.6'
bundle install
```

#### Create a controller

```
rails g controller Messages new create
```

#### Configure your route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :messages, only: [:new, :create]
  root to: "messages#new"
end
```

#### Controller code

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    require 'textmagic'

    @phone_number = message_params[:phone_number]
    @message = message_params[:message]

    @gateway = TextMagic::API.new('username', 'api_password')
    @gateway.send message_params[:message], message_params[:phone_number]
  end

private
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:phone_number, :message)
  end
end
```

#### Message View

Now let's set up our views. First open up the `new.html.erb` view for our `Messages` controller and modify it so that it looks like the code listed below.

```
<h2>Send a Text Message</h2>

<%= form_for :message, url: messages_path do |f| %>
<%= f.label :phone_number %>
<%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
<%= f.label :message %>
<%= f.text_field :message %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now let's modify our `create.html.erb` for the `Messages controller`. Open up the view and modify it so that it looks like the code listed below.

```
<h2>Message Sent!</h2>
<p>
<%= "The message to #{@phone_number} containing the text '#{@message}' has been sent successfully!" %>
</p>
<%= link_to "New Message", new_message_path %>
```

Now if we start a Rails server using rails s and navigate to http://localhost:3000 we can send a text message to anyone in the world. Note that we will need to use country codes in order to get TextMagic to utilize our phone number. For a US number that would be something like 15555551234 instead of 5555551234.